# Getting Images from SWF File

Tags: c#, .net, flash, webclient

I'm trying to write a page scraper that gets all the images on a page.  What I've already written works great except in the case of flash images.

The user pastes in a link, I scrape the page on the server side, and I return the images.  However, I want to all the images and often, hi-res images are in flash - [like this:](http://guessbymarciano.guess.com/en/Catalog/View/Apparel/Tops/Evening/Cecilia%20Beaded%20Tank/P24K1L01000)

However, since it is a swf file I don't know how to open it.  I found a couple of libraries like FlashTools and SWFDotNet, but I can't get any jive from either.  SWFDotNet doesn't handle versions greater than Flash 7 and FlashTools seems to tell me only generic data about the file, which I don't understand and can't utilize to get images from the file.  I've seen some references to an external API, but nothing for exactly what I want to do.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: can you give the url that you are trying to scrape images from..?

Comment: It is in the post:
http://guessbymarciano.guess.com/en/Catalog/View/Apparel/Tops/Evening/Cecilia%20Beaded%20Tank/P24K1L01000

Answer (score 0):

SWFDotNe should work for you I am not sure why you are having a problem getting this to work but if you have code written perhaps posting what you have thus far using SWFDotNe would help us to guide you or point you in the right direction. take a look at this site as well

[How to create a simple SWF decompiler with the SwfDotNet library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16834/How-to-create-a-simple-SWF-decompiler-with-the-Swf)

Comment: I appreciate your response, but SWFDotNet doesn't support versions of Flash greater than version 7.  So I get an error message saying that when I read the swf.